# Tridion advance search is not working properly

Tags: tridion

I am searching published component by advance search option in the publication,

I have selected one folder and searching published component.

Its search the published component but its does not search those component which is localized in the publication and has been published,

Do we have any option can also search localized published component or am i missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

Its should show localized component as well but any way not sure it may be issue with search.

You may find list of published component with a particular template using following steps.

The fact is you can republish all dynamic component already published by dynamic component template. From the same publish screen you can find already published components.

1. Locate to Dynamic CT in a publication
2. Select publish option, a publish dialog box will open
3. Select Targets
4. Click on "**See items to publish...**"
5. You will get the list of components published with that CT.

Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , for localised components you can select the particluar publication in the "Search box".
By this way your search will happen inside the selected publication.

Comment: when i select the folder from the publication, that means its search component only in that folder, then what does it means select the particular publication and where is this option in search box, i do not find this one

Comment: When you  Select a Publication  and open the "Search" list box .you will see two option (1) All Publication (2) Selected publication. you have to select option (2) to find publication specific localised component/page.

Comment: @RamS: please stop adding [core-services] tag to Tridion Core Service questions, the [core-services] tag is about a Cocoa Framework, not Tridion. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Services

Comment: @Nuno,Thanks for pointing out the fact .Could we have seperate tags for Tridion specific areas as Tridion-Core services , Tridion-Workflow , Tridion-templating etc as a lot of questions are tagged wrongly.

Comment: Not yet, that's why we're trying to get our own site with http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion - let's just stick with [Tridion] for now